# knex "Can't add new command when connection is in closed state"

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js, amazon-aurora

## Environment

Knex version: "knex": "^0.95.9",  "mysql2": "^2.2.5", "objection": "^2.1.2"

Database + version: Aurora MySQL - 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.01.0

OS:  Node.js 12 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.4.8

## Bug

1. Explain what kind of behaviour you are getting and how you think it should do

We are using knex in a recent project that is starting to grow a lot. We have a MySQL Aurora DB which has two different connections (endpoints): one for reading and another one to writing. Our application mainly consumes reading operations so we decided to create two knex instances and export two constants inside our project: DB_WRITE and DB_READ. Everything had been working ok with that configuration but recently we have been facing some high traffic periods and due to our database instances configurations for auto-scaling it starts to add new instances to the DB. The problem comes when those instances are deleted (auto-scale down) and a high percentage of the requests keep failing with the error I mentioned.

`"Can't add new command when connection is in closed state"`

We have been trying to apply some changes to the pool configurations in order to resolve the problem because we think that the pool is not correctly deleting the connections with the deleted instances but it didn't work correctly and we are having the same error. Our current pool configurations is the following:

`pool: { min: 0, max: 100, createTimeoutMillis: 3000, acquireTimeoutMillis: 30000, idleTimeoutMillis: 15000, reapIntervalMillis: 500, createRetryIntervalMillis: 100, // propagateCreateError: false, // <- default is true, set to false}, },`

2. Error message

`error: {"type":"error","message":"select`state`from`users`where`phone`= '+1234567890' and`users`.`deleted `is null limit 1 - Can't add new command when connection is in closed state"}`

This is really affecting our application in production environment and at this point we don't know what to do. If you have any advice or something that you think we are doing wrong it would be very helpful.

Comment: What code generates this error? BTW this might be helpful: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2321

Comment: After the DB replicas are deleted this happens every time we try to perform any action with the DB on our backend

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @MaicolLlanoMoncada - are you only looking to directly fix the pool and avoid the error? Or would mitigation strategies be helpful? 

I have possible approaches for using the knex query-error event handler, or hacky workaround approaches like manually removing connections that get that error.

Comment: @IvoHavener any mitigation strategy would be useful too, we haven't been able to find a solution yet so any recommendation from you would be awesome

Comment: @Nedudi No, we haven't been able to fin a solution

Answer (score 0):

**Requested Mitigation / Hacks**

Hopefully one of these work. Fair warning, I can't duplicate your error and test these suggestions.

Additional questions follow in case those answers inspire different suggestions.

- Define a validate function in the pool options that returns false if a simple query fails

  ```
   reapIntervalMillis: 500,
   validate: async (connection) => {
     try {
       // if failure takes too long set a timeout and resolve false at the timeout
       await connection.select('now()');
       return true;
     } catch () {
       return false;
     }
   },
   ...,
  ```

  The above option does add the overhead of a simple query each time you make your own query.

OR

- On error manually expire the connection so it's reaped by the pool, and set the reap interval ms to as small as doesn't cause performance problems.

  ```
   // make it very old so it's reaped
   knex.connection.timestamp = new Date('2000-01-01').getTime()
  ```

  This 2nd option uses undocumented functionality of tarn, the pool module, so you'd want to add a well documented test to validate that this works and the property exists as expected.

**Questions if those don't work**

Have you tried code other than just the pool config changes?

Do you try to manually destroying the connection itself? What happened if so?

Comment: And if you find anything broken (since I can't easily simulate this) I'm happy to update my response.

Comment: @MaicolLlanoMoncada - I'd appreciate feedback or a +1 when convenient